# Property body[41] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"

Tags: node.js, react-native

My react native project worked fine yesterday. But this morning, after I tried to run it again, it gave me the following error:

```
error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js: Property body[41] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression". Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
TypeError: Property body[41] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"
```

I'm not sure what it means, though. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, it may be a problem with the babel. Copy the folder `@babel` (specifically `@babel/core`) that is in the node_modules of a working project into the new project and it runs without problems.

It may be due to an update they did a couple of hours ago.

You can also remove the current `@babel/core` from the package.json and install this version `npm install --save-dev @babel/core@latest`.

Or use this:
 `@babel file`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view.

Or replace the following codes in your `package.json` file then `npm install`.

```
"@babel/core": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/compat-data": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/generator": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-module-transforms": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-replace-supers": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/types": "~7.14.0",
```

Answer (score 19):

This appears to be a bug with 7.15.0 of Babel which they are making a [E2E React native regression test](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/13639) for.

## Updated answer

A few hours ago they have released [the fix](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/13637).  It is due to a change to [@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name) which has been reverted in `7.15.1`.  With that fix, you should be able to remove the extra entries in the package.json from my original answer and instead do the following.

`npm install --save-dev @babel/core@latest`

## Original answer

Unfortunately, simply downgrading `@babel/core` to 7.14 will not be enough because it seems to pull the latest dependencies for the other components.  Instead what you need to do is lock down `@babel/core` and any other Babel component you are working that is coercing `@babel/types` to go to 7.15.0

Here's the relevant section I had in my package.json

```
"@babel/core": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/compat-data": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/generator": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-module-transforms": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/helper-replace-supers": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "~7.14.0",
"@babel/types": "~7.14.0",
```

Just replace all of that and perform an `npm install` and let it try to resolve and test your scenario again.  If it still fails just look at package-lock.json and locate `7.15.0` and adjust the dependency accordingly

With this approach you don't need to "recover" from a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is due to a babel update that affected the RN project.
copy @babel from some other project and paste in node_modules or
Download the @babel folder from here and replace the existing folder in the node_modules.[Babel Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view)

And run

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this come up when I change git branches and need to do a yarn install.
I like the comment to change the bable version since I'm also on 7.15 and I'll try this the next time it occurs...

To get around this I have successfully:

1. Stopped metro
2. ran a cleanup script (included below)
3. removed/uninstall app from device/simulator
4. started metro
5. installed app
6. sometimes I still get the error and do 1-5 again and it works.

my cleanup script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "clean'n android"
cd ./android && ./gradlew clean
cd ..

rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn cache clean
rm ./yarn.lock

rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-builder-cache-*

yarn install
```

Answer (score 1):

Pin `@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name` to `7.14.5`.

You can do it via adding this into your **package.json** if your package manager support `resolutions`.

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "7.14.5"
  }
```

---

Thank to [facebook/react-native#31960](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31960#issuecomment-893176992)

Answer (score -3):

copy @babel from some other project and paste in node_modules is the only solution for now

Comment: copying @babel is not working too for me.

Comment: you should try coping from some working project, its works for me well

Comment: try downloading from here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, I think @AbhishekVerma babel file would help.