# error: Expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression" | React Native IOS

Tags: react-native-ios

I'm having this problem when trying to run react native app on ios emulator.
I literally just created the project running `npx react-native init app_test` and when I run `npx react-native run-ios` I got this error.

[image]

I'm not installing dependencies or pods or anything. Just running `yarn start` when the app init is done and trying to run the emulator. Any suggestion by any chance plz?

Error in console:
`error: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/ImageAnalyticsTagContext.js: Property body[6] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"`

Comment: Having the same issue with a brand new project, The issue has been reported https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/issues/213

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native : Property body\[41\] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type \["Statement"\] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659516/react-native-property-body41-of-blockstatement-expected-node-to-be-of-a-type)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check this solution out: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31960#issuecomment-893176992.

It seems there is a problem with `@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.15.0` which has been released along with `@babel/core@7.15.0` a couple of hours ago.

Comment: downgrade to last minor version is still not working.

Comment: Run `npm install` or `yarn` again and reset your Metro cache with `npx react-native react-native start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to resolve the warnings after running 'yarn' or 'npm install'.

One of the relevant warnings is

```
warning "react-native > react-native-codegen > jscodeshift@0.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
```

I was able to resolve this issue by running:

```
yarn add @babel/preset-env@^7.1.6 -D
```

Edit: Spoke too soon. That did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

"resolutions": {
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "7.14.5"
}
add this in your package.json, and use yarn

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for people who are starting react-native as me, I'll explain what I did with detail. (I'm using Window10)

I did almost everything in StackOverflow to solve my problem. As you can see in many answers this problem is caused by babel.

I bet you download "yarn" while set up, you need to remove and re-download babel using yarn.
So, you need to put this below in your project root dir cmd
`$ yarn remove babel-preset-react-native`
`$ yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0`

But for me, this caused problem Bug: Yarn fails to install (Exit code: 128). So, I had to remove yarn and re-download using below

So I had to clean my cache to remove and re-downlaod yarn.lock using
`$ yarn cache clean`
`$ del yarn.lock`
(I didn't use this but maybe you need to erase node_modules file as well)
`$ yarn`

Then, I put below in my project's package.json below the "jest"
`"resolutions": { "@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "7.14.5" }`

For last, run my project using below.
`$ react-native run-android`

Hope this work for you as well it did for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

Download the @babel folder from here and replace the existing folder in node_modules and it works:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view