# react-native android won't run on device

Tags: react-native

i just started a project and im trying to start the but it already has this error showing:

error: node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image\ImageAnalyticsTagContext.js: Property body[6] of BlockStatement expected node to be of a type ["Statement"] but instead got "AssignmentExpression"

Comment: Additional Thread: [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659516/react-native-property-body41-of-blockstatement-expected-node-to-be-of-a-type)

Comment: i had a same problem, but using ios!

Comment: Follow the issue on Github to get more informations!
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31961

Comment: Please update node version to >= 12 if your using react-native 0.64

Comment: @Neil Alden Escobin mark Daniel Sá answer as accepted. So other get help from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue caused by a bug in a newly released version of babel. it will impact all new react-native and expo apps. you can resolve it with yarn resolutions in a new project:

```
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -25,5 +25,8 @@
   },
   "jest": {
     "preset": "react-native"
+  },
+  "resolutions": {
+    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "7.14.5"
  }
}
```

After insert resulutions key on the package.json, run `yarn install`

> Credits: https://github.com/brentvatne

> Issue Link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31961

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to a babel update that affected the RN project. copy @babel from some other project and paste in node_modules or Download the @babel folder from here and replace the existing folder in the node_modules.@Babel [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-z_4H_z4x075unZqZD41WYUwY_hsrKox/view)

And run

```
npm start --reset-cache
```